# How can I create a filled map with custom polygons in Tableau given point data?

Tags: tableau-api

In one TDE, I have individual posts from a hyperlocal social network with lat/long data. In the other TDE, I have polygons for Chicago's community areas.

How can I shade those community areas according to the number of records that were posted within its boundaries?

I'd like to essentially look up the community area by lat/long since I don't have the community area data within the first TDE to perform a join. Is there some other way to generate these shaded polygons given the data I already have? Is there another mapping tool that could do this for less than hundreds of dollars, if Tableau is not the answer?

[Here's my workbook on Tableau Public.](https://public.tableau.com/profile/libbyh#!/vizhome/chicago_sample/EveryBlockChicagoMetadata)

Comment: so basically you would like to "connect" every single row (first tde) of your hyperlocal social network (eg lat 42,010; long -87,670, schema:talk, nuber of record:1) to the relative polygon (other tde)which "contains" that point?

Comment: Yes, @FabioFantoni, I think so.

Comment: i think that one possible way to reach your goal could be a data-preparation stage before using Tableau... is that something you could do? I did something similar in the past, but I don't know if you want work ONLY "inside" Tableau

Comment: I can do data prep, but I'm not sure what exactly I need to do. I'm tempted to just do this all in Python instead of using Tableau at all. If Tableau can't help me with the lookup, that may actually be easier (or using the Postgres + PostGIS option in the answers).

Answer (score 0):

You could load both data sets into Postgres. Add the PostGIS extension, so you can do geospatial queries to map posts to polygons. The connect Tableau to Postgres to create your visualization. One step at a time.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Thanks, Alex. I'll give it a shot.